# primefaces example doesn't work

Tags: java, primefaces

i try to run an example from primefaces.org,
this one
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multiSelectListbox.jsf

but the result is

http://tinypic.com/r/j6icnl/5

this is my code
xhtml:

```
<h:body>

  <h:form>

    <p:multiSelectListbox value="#{multiSelectListboxBean.selection}" effect="slide">
        <f:selectItems value="#{multiSelectListboxBean.categories}" />
    </p:multiSelectListbox>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" update="out" style="margin:10px 0"/>

    <h:outputText id="out" value="Value: #{multiSelectListboxBean.selection}" style="display:block"/>

</h:form>
```

ManagedBean code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItemGroup;

        @ManagedBean(name="multiSelectListboxBean")
        @RequestScoped
        public class AddPacchettiBean {

            private List<SelectItem> categories;

            private String selection;

            @PostConstruct
            public void init() {
                categories = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                SelectItemGroup group1 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1");
                SelectItemGroup group2 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 2");
                SelectItemGroup group3 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 3");
                SelectItemGroup group4 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 4");

                SelectItemGroup group11 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1.1");
                SelectItemGroup group12 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 1.2");

                SelectItemGroup group21 = new SelectItemGroup("Group 2.1");

                SelectItem option31 = new SelectItem("Option 3.1", "Option 3.1");
                SelectItem option32 = new SelectItem("Option 3.2", "Option 3.2");
                SelectItem option33 = new SelectItem("Option 3.3", "Option 3.3");
                SelectItem option34 = new SelectItem("Option 3.4", "Option 3.4");

                SelectItem option41 = new SelectItem("Option 4.1", "Option 4.1");

                SelectItem option111 = new SelectItem("Option 1.1.1");
                SelectItem option112 = new SelectItem("Option 1.1.2");
                group11.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option111, option112});

                SelectItem option121 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.1", "Option 1.2.1");
                SelectItem option122 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.2", "Option 1.2.2");
                SelectItem option123 = new SelectItem("Option 1.2.3", "Option 1.2.3");
                group12.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option121, option122, option123});

                SelectItem option211 = new SelectItem("Option 2.1.1", "Option 2.1.1");
                group21.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option211});

                group1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{group11, group12});
                group2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{group21});
                group3.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option31, option32, option33, option34});
                group4.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{option41});

                categories.add(group1);
                categories.add(group2);
                categories.add(group3);
                categories.add(group4);
            }

            public List<SelectItem> getCategories() {
                return categories;
            }    

            public String getSelection() {
                return selection;
            }
            public void setSelection(String selection) {
                this.selection = selection;
            }
        }
```

i'dont get it, why !!!!

Comment: To me it looks like you have not setup the project correctly. Have a look at this tutorial about setting up primefaces tutorial eclipse and maven. Once you have done it then try this example.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INkvO9qzLnk

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing something on your Primefaces installation

- Make sure you are putting the Primefaces jars under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
- Check your Primefaces namespace declaration. (`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`)